# How to dynamically append selected option to a div and update if selected option is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my HTML: a `<select>`, and a `<div>`:

```
  <select>
    <option>Please select one</option>
    <option>Volvo</option>
    <option>Saab</option>
    <option>Mercedes</option>
    <option>Audi</option>
  </select>

  <div></div>
```

When I select an option, I want to append the being selected option value to the `<div>` element.
This in my `js` code:

```
    $('select').on('change', function (e){
             $('div').append("//not sure how to write code here");
    });
```

What should I add in the `append()`, so that when a user select an option, it will shows up on my `div`, if the user change to another option, it will update the content?

For example, if I select Volvo, "Volvo" text will show in my `div`, if I change to `Saab`, "Saab" text will show up in my `div` to replace "Volvo"

Comment: `$('#myDiv').text($(this).val());` Notice the id selectors.

Comment: @Teemu Would you mind adding that as an answer?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Actually I was working on an answer, but leo.fcx was faster ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.append` adds new `html element` inside the `target` element.

Use instead `$.text`. It will replace the `div` content to the new value. Also use `$.val` to get the current selected value from the `select` tag. Note that `this` refers to the `select` tag

Try this:

```
 $('select').on('change', function (e){
     $('div').text($(this).val());
 });
```

See demo:

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
  $('div').text($(this).val());
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px dashed #999;
  padding: 15px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Please select one</option>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>

<div>Anything selected yet</div>
```

Comment: The OP said that they want to append, not replace, implying that there could be other data already present in the div that should be preserved. If this is the case, then an empty span can be added to the div, and the text function can be called on this span, ensuring that any pervious contents remain in the div.

Comment: @MagikM18 Actually they want `.text()`: - *"if I change to Saab, "Saab" text will show up in my div to replace "Volvo""*

Comment: @Spencer Yes I understand this, perhaps I should clarify. I'm not saying that a new span should be added each time, I'm saying that if they have other text or HTML in the div (for example, "Currently selected: "), then they can use a span inside the div to accomplish this, and use the same span each time; this would result in "Currently selected: Volvo" or "Currently selected: Saab"

Comment: @MagikM18 In OP's example the div seems to be empty. You have a point though, when we need more generic code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text()` instead of `.append()`. Like below

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
  $('div').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Please select one</option>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know this is an old post, but while the initial answer helped, it was not the solution. I figured out a modification which *was* however, as follows:

`$('select').on('change', function (e){
        var lang = $(this).val();
        $('.someClass').append(lang);`

I am posting it incase it helps someone else. This will append the selected text to whatever you need it attached to. In my case, it was to attach it to an anchor.